# the jar of this class file belongs to container 'plug-in dependencies' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am creating a simple plugin to read the value from targeted console.For this i have written the below code.

```
private MessageConsole findConsole(String name) {
    ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
    IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
    MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);
    conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { myConsole });
    return myConsole;
}

/**
 * the command has been executed, so extract extract the needed information
 * from the application context.
 */
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

    IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
    String CONSOLE_NAME = window.getShell().getText();
    MessageConsole myConsole = findConsole(CONSOLE_NAME);
    out = myConsole.newMessageStream();
    out.println("Hello from Generic console sample action");

    myConsole.activate();
    myConsole.initialize();
    IOConsoleInputStream aa = myConsole.getInputStream();
    InputStream iStream = myConsole.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

    try {
        String a = buf.readLine();
        out.println(a);
        ATGHandler.main(null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It is generating a exception "the jar of this class file belongs to container 'plug-in dependencies' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries."
Please help me to come out from this problem.